# Ambiguous joke?

Tags: ambiguity

I want to refer to "a nice lawyer joke", where the joke is nice, not the lawyer. How can I do that unambiguously? Is it best to rephrase to something like "a nice joke about lawyers", which to me sounds a little clumsy?

Comment: I think hyphen will come to your rescue here. Compare nice-lawyer joke with nice lawyer-joke.

Comment: @Stockfish - yes, that does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Lawyer: "You have come to the right person for help but I must tell you my fees are high". Plaintiff: "Oh good! But how much do you charge?". Lawyer: "£50,000 for the answers to two questions". Plaintiff: "Heavens! That's rather a lot isn't it? Lawyer: "Yes. What's your second question?"

Comment: @Anton That qualifies as a "good bad-lawyer joke" :-)